# How to implement a trigger Before / After save method of Spring-Data Repository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I've got a big number of entities.
For every entity I've got an interface that extends `CrudRepository`.
Every entity is saved using `*Repository.save(entity)` method.

And I want to implement a logger like that:

- have a separate database for logs with two tables: log & logdata
- `log` table:

  - created
  - username
- `logdata` table:

  - log_id
  - fieldname
  - value (of string)
- when `save` or `delete` method runs, MyRepositoryTrigger should write a log message with all fields changed with field names and field values.

But how to write smth like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For trigger functionality you'll have to look at your DB but most likely it won't guarantee exclusivity of your `CrudRepository` DB activity since it's set upon creation/deletion/update of table/column.

If instead you want to imitate trigger functionality meaning something to fire without you having to set it up every single time before/after your `CrudRepository#save()/delete()` functionality then you are better off using `Spring AOP` functionality

```
@After("execution(* my.CrudRepository.save(..))")
public void log(JoinPoint point) {
    log.info(point.getSignature().getName() + " was called..");
}
```

You can find [extensive Spring AOP programming documentation in the Spring Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html)

Comment: Thank you, @dimitrisli, I know these ways and unfortunately they don't fit me. When working with DB trigger, I can't implement any business logic, like transforming entity's ids to names. But when using AOP methods, I can't work within current transaction - aop method is called from outside Spring transaction. So these are unsutable ways. Do you have any more ideas?

Comment: hi @omickron, please read about transactional advice in the link above or here linking directly the section: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to implement audit log for the changes. If you are using Spring Data JPA with Hibernate, I may recommend using [Hibernate Envers](http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/) that solves you everything. You add the maven dependency, then you add `@Audited` annotation on your entity (or on your interface), and envers will create an *_aud table for every entity you have audit on and add changelog automatically.

Storing user-id is a bit trickier, but you may [find example here in the documentation for that as well](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#envers-revisionlog).